# my json file does not match my graphQL queries

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, resolver, graphql-yoga

I'm using graphql-yoga and when I run the query users I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users'). Even though I surfed the internet and got help from chatgpt, I couldn't solve it.[myJsonFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W04qv.png) [schema.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJJD9.png) [query.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIXUZ.png) [index.js for resolvers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2zY9.png)

I'm sure my json file is not corrupt, I can print it when I want to print it to the console. When I did a little research, I thought it was context related, but I didn't know what to do.

Comment: show the relevant code and JSON content in the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, problem is in server.js [server.js_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f58mG.png)
When using createYoga, I only defined the schema, I added the context parameter next to the schema as shown in the figure and added my json file into it. and its working now [server.js_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfPg8.png)

Comment: Consider providing a smaller example of the code changes rather than just linking to some external resource twice